# Could someone reasonably bleed out from a puncture wound on the front of the thigh?

Tags: bleeding, arteries-artery, thigh, exsanguination

Could someone reasonably bleed out from a puncture wound on the front of the thigh?

I am by no means an expert in physiology or any related science, but to my knowledge I suppose the only thing they could cut is the superficial femoral artery? Or could they cut the popliteal artery?

I tried looking at some diagrams, but they were very unclear to my untrained eyes.

[image]